# Elasticsearch grouping of aggregation results

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

Hey im using the following aggregation:

```
 {    "size":0,    "aggs":
    {
      "ouType":
      {
         "terms":
          {
            "field":"ouType"
          } 
      }    
   } 
}
```

and I'm getting the following result :

```
aggregations: {    
  ouType: { ​​​ 
    buckets: (10) [
      0: Object { key: "ouType1", doc_count: 586 } ​​​​ 
      1: Object { key: "ouType2", doc_count: 521 } ​​​​
      2: Object { key: "ouType3", doc_count: 369 } ​​​​ 
      3: Object { key: "ouType4", doc_count: 297 } ​​​​ 
      4: Object { key: "ouType5", doc_count: 195 } ​​​​ 
      5: Object { key: "ouType6", doc_count: 177 } ​​​​ 
      6: Object { key: "ouType7", doc_count: 176 } ​​​​ 
      7: Object { key: "ouType8", doc_count: 102 } ​​​​ 
      8: Object { key: "ouType9", doc_count: 79 } ​​​​ 
      9: Object { key: "ouType10", doc_count: 65 }    
    ] ​}
```

now I would like to summarize the results together in other buckets, which are not in my datastructure or mapping. For example I would like to sum up

object 0 to 3 as `0: Object { key: "my_group1", doc_count: sumOf(doc_count object 0 to 3)}`, object 4 to 6 as `1: Object { key: "my_group2", doc_count: sumOf(doc_count object 4 to 6`) } and object 7 to 9 as `2: Object { key: "my_group3", doc_count: sumOf(doc_count object 7 to 9) }`

.

Is there any way to group these results in other buckets, after getting the result or do i have to work with pipeline aggregations of any type? thank you very much for you help!

Comment: Please format your JSON so that it's readable. Use this [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) if you don't know how to do that.

Comment: Is this better?

Comment: I meant the code in the text that comes after "I would like to sum up object...". Thanks

Comment: I changed it again, I hope it´s understandable